# How to pull the required columns from the csv file?

Tags: r

I have a grocery sales data which has 11 columns like store name,item name,price etc. For my analysis i do not require all the column values. I need only few column values for generating a report.

what is the R code for this?

Example: Below are the column names of an sales data. i need only 6 of the below column values. I tried that coding, but error is shown, also those answers I don't understand

```
STORE_NAME  STORE_ID    DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER    BILL_NUMBER BARCODE ITEM_NAME   VARIANT_NAME    BASEPACK    CATEGORY    BRAND   MANUFACTURER    QUANTITY_SOLD   PRICE   PURCHASE_PRICE  SELLING_PRICE   SALES_VAT   USER_NAME   COUNTER CUSTOMER_NAME   CUSTOMER_PHONE  BILL_DATE   CREATED_DATE
```

Comment: Check out [how to write a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). :)

Answer (score 0):

Read all the data with `read.table` or `read.csv` and then extract only those, that you can use. That's what we use square brackets for in `R`. You can do it either by column number or column name:

```
lots.of.cols <- data.frame(a=1:20, b=2:21, c=3:22, d=runif(20), e=runif(20))

only.first.two.cols <- lots.of.cols[,c(1,2)] #extract only column 1 and 2
str(only.first.two.rows)

only.a.and.b <- lots.of.cols[,c("a", "b")]
str(only.a.and.b)
```

Comment: Thanks bernad....its working....also i tried a different code like the below >tablename$STORE_NAME = NULL

Comment: There are endless ways to achieve this - square brackets are maybe the most versatile tool to have in your toolbox. If this was the right answer, please consider to hit the "accept this answer" button.